# django view not passing a value to the temple using render_to_response

Tags: python, django

I followed [this link](http://www.webforefront.com/django/setupdataviewmethodsfortemplates.html) and tried something similar in my django app. In my views.py i defined something like this:

```
def acadprogram(request):
    name = Program_requirement_category.objects.get(name='AS.SCIENCE')
    student_id = 2773951
    values = {'student_id':student_id}
    descendants = name.get_descendants(include_self=True)
    return render_to_response("courses.html", {'nodes':descendants.all()}, values, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

and i tried accessing the student_id like this:

```
<h3><font color=#428BCA>Caleb Streeter {{student_id}}</font></h3>
```

But django threw me an error as follows:

```
render_to_string() got multiple values for keyword argument 'context_instance'
```

SO how do i try passing the value through **render_to_response?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

Edit values to be

```
values = {'student_id':student_id, 'nodes':descendants.all() }
```

and return

```
render_to_response("courses.html", values, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

or simply

```
return render_to_response("courses.html", {'nodes':descendants.all(), 'student_id':student_id}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 2):

your student_id variable needs to be added to the dictionary where you have nodes.  something like this should work:

```
def acadprogram(request):
    name = Program_requirement_category.objects.get(name='AS.SCIENCE')
    student_id = 2773951
    descendants = name.get_descendants(include_self=True)
    values = {'student_id':student_id, 'nodes':descendants.all()}
    return render_to_response("courses.html", values, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def acadprogram(request):
    values = {}
    name = Program_requirement_category.objects.get(name='AS.SCIENCE')
    values['student_id'] = student_id = 2773951
    values['descendants'] = name.get_descendants(include_self=True)
    return render(request, "courses.html", values)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use locals() to pass local variables to template render.

```
return render_to_response('your/template.html', 
                          locals(), 
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request)
```